# springBoot application on Jboss EAP, servlet context not lodaed

Tags: maven-3, spring-boot, jboss-eap-6

I have a very simple spring boot application that I want to deploy to Jboss EAP. Here is my simple application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class MayurApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MayurApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<MayurApplication> applicationClass = MayurApplication.class;
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

and my pom.xml is also very basic. When I run this application on Tomcat, using the embedded Tomcat what ships with spring boot. Everything works like charm in just one click. I can access `http://localhost:8080/demo/hello/World` and it works too.

Now I tried to make it Jboss EAP compatible war, I disabled the Tomcat by excluding from spring-boot-starter-web, and convert it into a war project. (as suggested by article http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

I also added:

```
<dependency>
                  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                 <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>,
```

as it was complaining.

Now after all this, it compiles fine and creates a war too. When I copied this war to jboss deployment, I can see it successfully deployed on console. 
But the rest api `http://localhost:8080/demo/hello/World` just does not work and constantly throws error on browser:

```
JBWEB000068: message /demo/hello/World
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is here :  [Spring Java Config vs Jboss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7/21314659#comment32870531_21314659)

Apparently "/" does not work on Jboss EAP 6.3 , but "/*" works.
and they seems to have fixed it with wildfly 8

Answer (score 18):

Found this in [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix), add the below line in application.properties file

```
server.servlet-path=/*
```

tested this in jBoss EAP 6.2 and worked fine.

Comment: this worked. I think the explanation is in the correctly marked answer.

Comment: Please, fix this answer: use server.servlet.path

Comment: I mean, the - should be a dot .

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned JBoss 6 in you tags. Based on my experience Spring Boot **Autoconfigure** and JBoss 6 (specifically) is a no-go. If Hot Deploy is turned on or perhaps some other condition JBoss VFS performs some aggressive scanning of all jars in the war file. Once it starts to scan the classes in the autoconfigure module, it will abort due to an error akin to ClassNotFoundException. If you are using Autoconfigure, one solution might be to place the spring modules in the Container's lib. But this would make deployment unwieldy. I did not see this behavior on JBoss 7 nor Wildfly 8.

Comment: Actually - I am now able to successfully deploy multiple Spring Boot Applications with JBoss 6. The key to this accomplishment was using the jboss-scanning.xml deployed in the jar to tell JBoss not to try and load every class in Autoconfigure lib. There are some other tweaks as well that I have been meaning to write up but the jboss-scanning.xml was key.

Comment: Can you provided your jboss-scanning.xml that fixed the problem?

Comment: @ddcruver - it has been a few years since I have been on the project but if you send me your currently scanning.xml file, I might be able to point out the changes I made.