# Springboot 1.3.3 gives 404 in Jboss EAP 6.4.0GA

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a spring `.war` into jboss but am getting 404 errors. I know this has been asked before:

- [springBoot application on Jboss EAP, servlet context not lodaed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576629/springboot-application-on-jboss-eap-servlet-context-not-lodaed)
- [Spring Java Config vs Jboss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7)
- [Cannot deploy Spring Boot on jBoss EAP 6.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870599/cannot-deploy-spring-boot-on-jboss-eap-6-3-3)

But I am very new (this week) to maven/spring/jboss, so may well have messed up. I tried what I understood from the various solutions above and none of them worked for me. Probably me messing up or missing something. So I thought I'd get the problem as simple as I can.

I took the code from:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git
And then work in the `complete` folder.

```
cd complete 
mvn package
java -jar .\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
```

And that all worked as you'd expect.

So then I followed the instructions here (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) to modify my code and `pom.xml` to produce a war file.

- pom.xml http://pastebin.com/BiLWDskd
- Application.java http://pastebin.com/par7rftz

I then `mvn clean package` and load the resulting .war file into EAP using the UI (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7zxG.png).

So then in theory this should be the URL right

- http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting

I also tried

- http://localhost:8080/greeting

But am getting the 404 error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6J6z.png) as described in the other questions. Nothing appears in the jboss console log at all after the .war is loaded.

So am I missing something? Do I need to write a jboss @WebServelet class to wrap around the spring stuff? Changes to my pom.xml? Should I not be using springboot, and just just pring framework modules directly? I note that in the EAP screen it does not show the class in the third column like it did with the jboss sample `.war`.

Remember I am new to this, so please explain stuff as if I'm a complete dummy (which I am).

Details of my setup:

- OS Windows7 x64
- java version "1.8.0_91"
- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- Springboot 1.3.3
- JBOSS EAP 6.4.0
- No IDE, using vim and command line

Comment: Did you check JBoss log file for any errors that might occurred?

Comment: There a line or two added when I load the .war, and then a heap of output when I enable it. But no logging when requests are issued. Log is here: http://pastebin.com/uscADLVN You can see it does something with the /greeting mapping

Comment: UPDATE: I have spring working in jboss now, but not with spring boot. It required defining a servelt in the XML files. If I don't get a proper answer, I'll post the various XML I used to do it.

Comment: Hi @Sodved, same issue here and pretty much the same configuration. Would that be possible for you to post an answer with your solution? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on JBoss EAP 6.4 / spring boot 1.5 and what fixed it was to add this property to application.properties

server.servlet-path=/*

as explained in this post : [Deploying spring boot on JBOSS EAP 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737129/deploying-spring-boot-on-jboss-eap-6-1)

A simple tutorial you can follow (though he miswrote the property server.servlet.path )
http://code-adda.com/2018/06/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-war-in-jboss/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.