# DIsabling JBoss EAP 6.4 basic authentication

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-security, spring-boot, jboss-eap-6

I have Spring Boot application which use Spring Security OAuth2 as the protection. The application worked well when tested using default server. However, when I try to deploy it on JBoss EAP 6.4 , the application expects the CSRF token. How do I disable JBoss' basic authentication so that my application does not require CSRF token?

EDIT:

As I have described at the comment for sadasidha's answer, this problem didn't show up on Wildfly 8 (JBoss AS)

Answer (score 0):

Disable csrf protection. It's enabled by default

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Disable 
        http.csrf().disable();
    // ...... }
```

Comment: Nope, still asking for the CSRF token. Btw, when I use the default server, I don't have to disable the CSRF, it is automatically disabled. I can;t use CSRF because I'm developing API which is accessed with CURL

Comment: Surprisingly my application run well on Wildfly 8 (JBoss AS).

Comment: can you give me your log

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Actually it is the result of mapping problem. I'm following the solution from 
[Spring Java Config vs Jboss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7/)