# Java config for Spring: correct deploy but 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I am creating a basic Spring MVC + Repositories + Security configuration.
I leveraged [THIS GUIDE](http://www.sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa.html) and got to the configuration I am reporting below.
According to that configuration, I would expect some welcome page to show up at `localhost:8080/HPLAN/welcome`; I also get redirected to that URL after typing `localhost:8080/HPLAN/`, but I always get a 404 error. Server log does not receive any request (server log does not show any "no request mapping"). At the deployment location "HPLAN" folder is present.
I also need to mention that database tables are NOT created.

So, my configuration is this:

1. Security

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @Autowired
   private DataSource dataSource;

   @Autowired
   private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
       registry.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/login/form**", "/register", "/logout")
               .permitAll() // #4
               .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // #6
               .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
               .and().formLogin() // #8
               .loginPage("/login/form") // #9
               .loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureUrl("/login/form?error").permitAll(); // #5
   }
   ```

   }
2. Persistence

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tek4b.hplan.repositories")
   public class PersistenceConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Value("${init-db:false}")
   private String initDatabase;

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory().getObject();
       return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

       HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
       vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);

       factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       factory.setPackagesToScan("com.tek4b.hplan.entities");

       Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
       jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
       factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

       factory.afterPropertiesSet();
       factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
       return factory;
   }

   @Bean
   public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
       return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
       dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
       dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
       dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
       return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
       DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
       dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
       ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
       databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db.sql"));
       dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
       dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(initDatabase));
       return dataSourceInitializer;
   }
   ```

   }
3. AppConfig

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
       "com.tek4b.hplan" }, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = {
               "com.tek4b.hplan.web.*" }) )
   @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
   @EnableScheduling
   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
   @EnableCaching
   public class AppConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }

   @Bean
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
       return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
   }
   ```

   }
4. MVC:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.tek4b.hplan.web" })
   @EnableWebMvc
   public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       super.addViewControllers(registry);
       registry.addViewController("login/form").setViewName("login");
       registry.addViewController("welcome").setViewName("welcome");
       registry.addViewController("admin").setViewName("admin");
   }

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver resolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver url = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
       url.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return url;
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }

   @Override
   public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
   }

   @Bean(name = "messageSource")
   public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
       ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
       messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
       messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
       messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
       return messageSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
       SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
       Properties mappings = new Properties();
       mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "error");
       b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
       return b;
   }
   ```

   }
5. Web.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   version="3.0">
   <display-name>HPLAN</display-name>
   ```

My project structure:

[image]

I created the database and the server seems to start correctly:

```
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: <hidden by me>;.
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HPLAN' did not find a matching property.
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 694 ms
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [281] milliseconds.
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 13, 2015 7:26:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2767 ms
```

Then it stands like that regardless of my requests.
What's wrong with it?

============UPDATE
6. AppInitializer class:

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"),
                new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter() };
    }

}
```

Comment: Did u checked your application deployed or not?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi It is actually deployed at the tomcat deployment folder with its correct name (HPLAN). I updated my OT.

Comment: As u mentioned you are using Tomcat for deployment so it have to show which war its deployed did you saw that? Sometimes i also faces in eclipse+Tomcat or Eclipse+Jboss Server started but project nt deployed

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I connected my Tomcat 7 to eclipse (STS), then I created an instance of it and selected "Run on server" to run my HPLAN application. This way, at the deployment location, I don't see a WAR, but a folder named HPLAN.

Comment: You right click on project then click on  `Run on Sever` ? Do one thing if you war deploy manually in tomcat also read my previous comment

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Yes. Also, I tried to drag the project to the server to deploy it. Nothing changes.

Comment: Let me also mention that database tables are not created, so something wrong during deployment.

Comment: Where is your `WebAppInitializer` class?

Comment: It show deployment not done, checks logs it will tell clear picture what exception come on deployment

Comment: @DonBottstein I updated my OT.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi In the logs folder I only find localhost_access_log.2015-08-13, reporting GET methods and their corresponding 404 errors.

Comment: What about `server.log` file have any issue?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Where can I find it? There is no server.log in the logs folder at the deployment location. Also, there no file in the tomcat executable folder.

Comment: Whatever link you are using for your application ..Are you using same code or you are making  changes in your application?

Comment: no, no changes, except in the server log to hide my path variable

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getServletMappings()`, change

```
return new String[] { "/" };
```

to

```
return new String[] { "/*" };
```

Source :
[Spring Java Config vs Jboss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7)

Answer (score -1):

Your project doesn't have the "Dynanic Web Project" Facet.

Right-Click the project, and select "Properties". And then click on "Project Facet". Select the "Dynamic Web Project" and proceed with next steps there.

**UPDATE**
If that is OK, then check the "Deployment Assembly" in Project Properties tab. The source folders should be having target of "WEB-INF/classes", and other such things related to deployment.

If that is also OK, then you need to go to the "Servers" view, and delete the server from there. Restart Eclipse. And then Add a new Server.

Comment: It actually does, module v3.0.

Comment: If its wont  web project then right click on project should not show  `Run on Sever`

Comment: Added an update. I think that should address the issue. I don't think this is Spring related at all. It all about Eclipse and the WTP stuff.

Comment: Agree with @Mecon comment

Comment: That doesn't work. It is Spring-related, as it cannot initialize the database for some reason.

Comment: @Manu I think it not Spring related because the tomcat log you posted has  no line about the webapp being deployed. Usually if there is an issue with the app the Tomcat log will have msgs about webapp being attempted and then followed by msg about the app failing to deploy.

Comment: @Manu i told you same thing your application not deployed