# Spring Boot 1.3.3 Application with Tiles 3 on JBoss 6.4 - Error JBWEB000065 - 404 Not Found

Tags: jboss, spring-boot, tiles, jboss6.x, tiles-3

I am strugging to deploy a Spring Boot War Application (**with Tiles views**) on JBoss EAP 6.4. This application runs smoothly on Tomcat 8 but when I deploy it on JBoss it doesn't answer. The startup logs are OK but when I call a controller from the browser I get error **JBWEB000065**. I happens both deploying from Eclipse STS and putting the war in standalone/deployments.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.codependent.gitprofiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>boot3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ServletInitializer**:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Boot3Application.class);
    }

}
```

**Boot3Application**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Boot3Application {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Boot3Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**TilesConfiguration**:

```
@Configuration
public class TilesConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
         final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
         configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml" });
         configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
         return configurer;
     }

     @Bean
     public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
         final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
         resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
         return resolver;
     }

}
```

**Startup Logs**:

```
[org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) JBAS018210: Registrar el contexto web: /boot3
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/boot3]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@57c6298e, com.codependent.gitprofiles.ServletInitializer@16df6757]
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (background-preinit) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-2
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) 
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) 

[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Mapped "{[/home]}" onto public java.lang.String com.codependent.gitprofiles.Boot3Application.home()
...
```

Calling `http://localhost:8080/boot3/home` on the browser shows the following with nothing appearing on the JBoss logs;

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /boot3/error
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
JBWEB000068: message /boot3/error
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
```

**UPDATE**: I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7/21314659#comment32870531_21314659) on Stackoverflow but it useless in my case: using `server.servlet-path=/*` the application starts processing the requests, now the controller is invoked BUT it's unable to render the **Tiles views**:

```
Cannot forward to error page for request [/home] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

I have checked on Tomcat that if I use `server-servlet-path/*` it doesn't work either (with the same error) but it does with `/`.

To sum up, in JBoss I cannot have both `server.servlet-path=/*` (to allow the invocation on controllers) and `server.servlet-path=/` to allow the Tiles views rendering, so how can I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem. After installing the Jboss patch jboss-eap-6.4.6-patch.zip the problem does not occur anymore.

After patching I did not need to use the setting server.servlet-path=/*

Comment: I'm gonna try the patch