# Trying to deploy Spring application on old JBoss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jboss

The log message doesn't tell me anything I could use to locate and solve the problem

**domain/servers/appserver-centos/log/server.log**

```
2017-01-05 16:13:16,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | DeploymentServiceListener constructor for deployment restapi.war]
2017-01-05 16:13:16,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "restapi.war"
2017-01-05 16:13:18,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry idb.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry classes12.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry jta-spec1_0_1.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry log4j.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-logging.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,090 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015960: Class Path entry p6psy.jar in /content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool-1.5.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,117 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-20)  | JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser,org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
2017-01-05 16:13:18,252 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-9)  | JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:83) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]

2017-01-05 16:13:18,253 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-9)  | JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:83) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]

2017-01-05 16:13:18,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-15)  | JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.restapi.war:main" from Service Module Loader
2017-01-05 16:13:18,520 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,446 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,520 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,446 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,520 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,446 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [vfs:/content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-codegen-distribution-2.1.0-M1.jar/logback.xml]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,456 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@2bcadeba - URL [vfs:/content/restapi.war/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-codegen-distribution-2.1.0-M1.jar/logback.xml] is not of type file
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,477 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,487 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,516 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,516 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,516 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,517 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.wordnik] to DEBUG
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,517 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,517 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,518 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 16:13:18,519 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@7fb13d11 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2017-01-05 16:13:18,521 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2017-01-05 16:13:18,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2017-01-05 16:13:18,952 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)
2017-01-05 16:13:18,952 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | 
2017-01-05 16:13:20,163 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | Context [/restapi] startup failed due to previous errors
2017-01-05 16:13:20,163 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11)  | MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:97)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]

2017-01-05 16:13:20,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (host-controller-connection-threads - 9)  | JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "restapi.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"restapi.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
2017-01-05 16:13:20,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (host-controller-connection-threads - 9)  | JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./restapi: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

2017-01-05 16:13:20,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-5)  | JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.restapi.war:main" from Service Module Loader
2017-01-05 16:13:20,470 WARN  [com.alicecallsbob.fas.oamp.extension.OampServiceImpl] (MSC service thread 1-5)  | no MBean found when undeploying restapi.war
2017-01-05 16:13:20,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5)  | JBAS015877: Stopped deployment restapi.war in 215ms
```

**My maven file**, I'm pretty sure not all dependencies are required to be there for the project, like the bottom 4, but otherwise JBoss throws ClassNotFoundException.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapi</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>restapi</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-testing</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>restapi</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <extensions>false</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**Application properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Maybe the suggestions here could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666513/spring-java-config-vs-jboss-7

Comment: @ElvisRocha thanks, that put me on a track and found main problem. JBoss 7 was unable to create beans of CrudRepository interfaces, also seems there is a problem with entityManager with Hibernate5. I downgraded to Hibernate4 and repalced CrudRepositories with DAOs and all works again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not define any constructors, there is a default no argument constructor. If you define a constructor, then there will not be a no argument constructor unless you explicitly define it.

Spring framework is not shipped with  any of JBoss EAP release distributions. 
While you can package your own Spring implementation in your application, it is not recommended since the JavaEE 6 requires JBoss to provide an implementation. If you package your own Spring implementation then it will be considered part of your application.

You must package the spring libraries in your application and to make sure you should create a module for this and use it in your application.

Refer the below link:
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToCreateSingleSpringApplicationContextViaJBossModules

Comment: I found a problem, JBoss7 is unable to create bean of interface extending CrudRepository or JpaRepository. When I removed them and replaced with DAORepository it worked.